# locate-library vs find-library in emacs

Tags: emacs

What is the difference between `locate-library` and `find-library` in emacs?

I can run `locate-library` <kbd>Enter</kbd> `sql` and a full path would be written to the status string.

But `find-library` <kbd>Enter</kbd> `sql` returns: `find-library-name: Can't find library sql` (written to the `*Messages*` buffer).

Comment: I've found that I have only `.elc` files, not `.el` or `.el.gz`. After installing tham all works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `locate-library` shows the library name and path that would be used by a `load-library` (it may be a compiled `.elc`)
- `find-library` returns the library **source** (and fails if it does not find the `.el`)

Comment: To be more precise, `find-library` loads the source code into a buffer.  It's a specialized version of `find-file`.

Comment: More generally, the convention is that `find-*` functions will load the source for the specified thing into a buffer: `find-file`, `find-library`, `find-variable`, `find-function`, `find-face-definition`. Or perhaps more correctly, the convention is that functions which need to act in this manner have this prefix, as there *are* `find-*` functions for other purposes as well (particularly relating to the Unix `find` command).